# Is it a bad idea to auto-scroll to title of the page bypassing the header?

Tags: scrolling, header, title

In one of the sites I developed, I want visitors to auto-scroll to the title of the page (blog) by passing the **header** of the website.

Only main page shows everything as usual. Inline pages doesn't show the header at the top. At the top, the title of the page will show *by auto-scrolling* and if you scroll up you can see the header.

I want to do this to **show more content** to visitors, at first.

### This is the "normal" one:

[image]

### And this is the one I want to do:

[image]

*Note that the header still exist but you should scroll up to see header.*

### Is it a bad thing to auto-scroll to title of the page bypassing the header for UX?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: @Majo0od, I want to do this to show more content to visitors. Both screenshot has the same height but as you can see the second one displays more content (text).

Comment: That's correct, but the thing here is why do it in the first place, unless the content was being hidden entirely for some reason, I see a potential reason why. But as is, it's not vital for the user to get everything at once. They are going to naturally scroll. If it scrolls down, there could be an issue of "why did this just scroll on me."

Comment: Don't do anything weird with your site unless there's a strong reason for it. Showing more content isn't a strong reason. This is a blog. People know how to look at content on a blog already. You don't need to help them by doing confusing scrolly things with your homepage.

Answer (score 2):

## Users will have no sense of context

What if they got on that page from a different perspective? Possibly…
… they got there through Google
… they open the browser with an old session restored
… they open the page in a new tab in the background

In these cases they might not know or remember what website this page belongs to.

Yes it’s easy to scroll up or to check the address bar, but will people expect that to be necessary? If the context is lost, relevancy can also be gone, and it’s just as tempting to close the page as it is easy to scroll up.

### You risk losing visitors

@SamsonTennela has a good point that this is also bad for the branding of the site and I share the idea of the smaller header. A small title and/or logo, a few navigation options and even breadcrumbs are better than giving no context at all.

#### Technically not ideal (possibly)

If there is a good solution to this I would like to hear from it. As far as I know you can only scroll the page with javascript after the content is loaded (otherwise there is nothing to scroll). This means that the user might be reading or scrolling already when the page suddenly jumps to the new scrolling position. You can imagine that this is unwanted behavior and animate the scroll movement doesn't improve that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I thought the things you mentioned under "Possibbly...". I want to do this with JavaScript and it only works if the visitor comes from main page or another inline-page. If the visitor directly comes from Google etc. the scrolling code doesn't work (not active). Yes, I have the JS code and use it, if you want I can share. (No, not after the content is loaded. It's also smooth scrolling and doesn't have a bad affect on visitor).

Comment: Good to hear you thought of this already. The statement still stands when the page is loaded in a new tab though. I wanted to get rid of such scrolling function in one of the projects I work on. If you are willing to create a jsfiddle (or something alike) and share it here in the comments I will be very pleased.

Answer (score 1):

Not a bad idea but you are losing the branding of the site by hiding the logo. As an alternative you can show the header with smaller logo to save the header space and present the targeted content to the visitor with little scroll. Something like [theverge.com](http://theverge.com) inside pages when you scroll a little.

Comment: Agreed I think a mini-nav on those pages would be much more successful than hiding the nav

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I'm using the big-header -> tiny-header in one of my websites.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to correct this by having a smaller fixed logo appear after you reach a certain scroll position. That way when you want to scroll back up to the blog title the name of the site is still represented.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not a bad idea and I feel it's good to go option. In the blogging site, content is important than branding.

Your design is more focused on content. That's really good thought.

Branding is not completely hidden, it's visible on scroll up.